# question about class and function in python

Tags: python, function, class

Make a new class called Count. This class accepts two arguments: the name of the person who is counting, and the starting number for counting. Then write,
player1 = Count('Anna', 5)
player2 = Count('Barry', 8)
make a function called start_count in that class so that when you write player1.start_count() it will give the following output:
Anna is starting to count from 5. Start!
5... 4... 3... 2... 1... 0!

My codes are below, but my codes looks not so smart:

```
class count:
  def __init__(self, name, number):
    self.name = name
    self.number = number

player1 = count("Anna", 5)
player2 = count("Barry", 8)
print(player1.name,player1.number)
print(player2.name,player1.number)
def start_count(start, *skip):
    return [num for num in reversed(range(start + 1)) if num not in skip]
print("Anna is starting to count from 5. ")
print("start!")
print("... ".join(map(str, count_down(5))) + "!")
```

I think I should not put the number like 5 in the input position but a function like number() or input(),right? then how to change this?

Comment: `start_count()` should be implemented as a method under `count` class. Also class name should start with a capital as in your task description: `Count`

Comment: and you are mixing functionalities. Player should have a Counter an be a class on it's own, thought

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We generally use Pascal Case while naming classes in python (in contrast to snake case for variables and functions), so your class name should be `Count`. You should also put the function *inside* the class definition.

```py
class count:
   def __init__(self, name, number):
      self.name = name
      self.number = number

   def start_count(self):
      return [num for num in reversed(range(self.number + 1))]

player1 = count("Anna", 5)
player2 = count("Barry", 8)

print("Anna is starting to count from 5")
print("... ".join(map(str, player1.start_count())) + "!")
```

Comment: You are right! exactly I want to put the function inside the class definition!